# POST request to REST API with JSON object as payload in UNITY Getting ERROR

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am calling an API but its giving me below error:

> UriFormatException: Absolute URI is too short

Please check below code:

```
void updatePlayer ()
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create (requestURL) as HttpWebRequest;
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add ("x-api-key", "e1Zdd1YD92aJtpyDaCtSDTZCrDXtv2c9Cf");
    string json = "{" +
        "'firstName': '100'," +
        "'lastName': 'DEF'" +
        "}"; 

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) {

        streamWriter.Write (json);
    }
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = json.Length;

    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse ();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd ();
        //Now you have your response.
        //or false depending on information in the response
        Debug.Log (responseText);            
    }   
}
```